Ubuntu Docker Image for Windows
#FROM ubuntu:jammy-20230425
FROM ubuntu:lunar-20230615

# RUN apt update && \
#     DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y mate-desktop-environment-extras locales sudo

RUN sudo apt-get update; \
    sudo apt-get -y upgrade; \
    sudo apt-get install -y gnupg2 wget lsb_release 

RUN apt update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y xrdp tigervnc-standalone-server && \
    adduser xrdp ssl-cert && \
    locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 && \
    update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8

ARG USER=testuser
ARG PASS=1234

RUN useradd -m $USER -p $(openssl passwd $PASS) && \
    usermod -aG sudo $USER && \
    chsh -s /bin/bash $USER

RUN echo "#!/bin/sh\n\
export XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=mate\n\
export XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11\n\
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=MATE\n\
export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-mate:/etc/xdg\n\
exec dbus-run-session -- mate-session" > /xstartup && chmod +x /xstartup

RUN mkdir /home/$USER/.vnc && \
    echo $PASS | vncpasswd -f > /home/$USER/.vnc/passwd && \
    chmod 0600 /home/$USER/.vnc/passwd && \
    chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER/.vnc

RUN cp -f /xstartup /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh && \
    cp -f /xstartup /home/$USER/.vnc/xstartup

RUN echo "#!/bin/sh\n\
sudo -u $USER -g $USER -- vncserver -rfbport 5902 -geometry 1920x1080 -depth 24 -verbose -localhost no -autokill no" > /startvnc && chmod +x /startvnc

EXPOSE 3389
EXPOSE 5902

CMD service dbus start; /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind & service xrdp start; /startvnc; bash

I am trying to solve a problem for my windows docker i tried to install this dockerfile but it doesn't work it fails in the second command
can someone give me or fix for me this code or direct me to another image to launch linux in container

#########

Drop the sudo.

This setup seems like you're trying to set up an interactive desktop environment.  Would a virtual machine running a standard Ubuntu installation be easier?  Including the password in plain text in the Dockerfile isn't usually a security best practice, and commands like service often don't work in Docker the way you expect.

Remove "sudo" from all the commands.
Normally, docker containers are run using the user root. So you dont have to explicitly add sudo to the commands

is sudo the only problem of the dockerfile? have you run the dockerfile after dropping all sudo?

Ahh My Bad, I did not try running the full Dockerfile. The OP has asked about the issue in the second command, so, I just went with debugging that one.
